# Evaluating the value of an empty string

Tags: javascript

Why is

```
console.log('' == false); //true
```

but

```
console.log('' === false); //false
```

Based on [this](http://www.mapbender.org/JavaScript_pitfalls%3a_null,_false,_undefined,_NaN) the last row should return true, right?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because `===` checks for types and the string is a string and false is a boolean.

Answer (score 2):

No, when you use `===` in javascript you're also comparing **type**, [see this article](http://longgoldenears.blogspot.co.uk/2007/09/triple-equals-in-javascript.html) which explains in more detail.